# Can we setDT on multiple object all at once?

Tags: r, data.table

I need to load many rds files from outside, to make things go much smoother, I tend to setDT on the objects.

Is it possible to setDT all at once? I tried:

```
lapply(ls(), setDT)
lapply(list(ls()), setDT)
for(i in ls()) setDT(i)

#Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
#  Argument 'x' to 'setDT' should be a 'list', 'data.frame' or 'data.table'
```

The results are all the same. Is there more graceful way to doing this?

p.s. A friend advised using `do.call`:

```
do.call(setDT, list("A", "B", "C"))
```

but that seems not to be working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `Filter` `data.frame`s in an environment and apply `setDT` to those:

```
all_data_tables = Filter(function(x) is.data.frame(eval(as.name(x))), ls())
lapply(all_data_tables, function(x) setDT(eval(as.name(x))))
```

You can also potentially replace `is.data.frame` with `is.list` or something more complicated, but I think `is.data.frame` covers your use case.

You can also use `get` and could also be more careful about specifying `envir` in `ls`/`eval`/`get`.

Comment: @MichelChirico, Thanks, Michael. Now I know it's about the class of the value input.

Comment: @Grec001 don't be intimidated by error messages -- they're your friend! "Argument 'x' to 'setDT' should be a 'list', 'data.frame' or 'data.table'"